# Passing a url variable after submitting a form

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I'm working on a simple website where I can register isolated information systems in a simple database, and assign harddisks to each system using ForeignKeys. When deleting a system from the database, I use a DeleteView.

In the DeleteView: To check if there are any harddisks associated with the system I use custom method. If no harddisks are found, it displays the DeleteView form. If there are any, a list of the relevant harddisks is displayed instead of the form, with a link to the UpdateView of each individual harddisk.

*I want to be able to click a link to one of these harddisk, make changes to it in the UpdateView, then be redirected back to the DeleteView to "check the list again".*

This is what I have so far (Media = harddisk/storage media)

```
class MediaEdit(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
model = Media
form_class = MediaForm
template_name = 'dsl/media/media_create-edit.html'
success_message = 'Media successfully changed!'

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('dsl:media_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().id})

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MediaEdit, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['action'] = reverse('dsl:media_edit',
                                kwargs={'pk': self.get_object().id})
    next_url = self.request.GET.get('next', 'None')
    context['next_url'] = next_url
    return context
```

I have tried using the "next_url" variable in my UpdateView form:

```
{% if next_url %}
<form class="" action="{{ next_url }}" method="post">
{% else %}
<form class="" action="{{ action }}" method="post">
{% endif %}
```

The next_url works as intended if I change my UpdateView form to "GET", but then it doesn't save the changes I made in the UpdateView. And if I use "POST" it saves my changes, but throws a ProtectedError in the DeleteView.

**How can I make this work?**